# Youtube API - categories while uploading

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I need to upload a video using youtube API and .NET (c#).

```
newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
```

The category is set to "`Autos`". Where can I find a table with correct values of category names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here ["Category list for uploaded videos"](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#YouTube_Category_List)

http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<app:categories xmlns:app='http://www.w3.org/2007/app' xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007' fixed='yes' scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'>
  <atom:category term='Film' label='Film &amp; Animation' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:assignable/>
    <yt:browsable regions='AE AR AU BD BE BG BR CA CL CO CZ DE DK DZ EE EG ES ET FI FR GB GH GR HK HR HU ID IE IL IN IR IS IT JO JP KE KR LT LV MA MX MY NG NL NO NZ PE PH PK PL PT RO RS RU SA SE SG SI SK SN TH TN TR TW TZ UA UG US VN YE ZA'/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Autos' label='Autos &amp; Vehicles' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:assignable/>
    <yt:browsable regions='AE AR AU BD BE BG BR CA CL CO CZ DE DK DZ EE EG ES ET FI FR GB GH GR HK HR HU ID IE IL IN IR IS IT JO JP KE KR LT LV MA MX MY NG NL NO NZ PE PH PK PL PT RO RS RU SA SE SG SI SK SN TH TN TR TW TZ UA UG US VN YE ZA'/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Music' label='Music' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:assignable/>
    <yt:browsable regions='AE AR AU BD BE BG BR CA CL CO CZ DE DK DZ EE EG ES ET FI FR GB GH GR HK HR HU ID IE IL IN IR IS IT JO JP KE KR LT LV MA MX MY NG NL NO NZ PE PH PK PL PT RO RS RU SA SE SG SI SK SN TH TN TR TW TZ UA UG US VN YE ZA'/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Animals' label='Pets &amp; Animals' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:assignable/>
    <yt:browsable regions='AE AR AU BD BE BG BR CA CL CO CZ DE DK DZ EE EG ES ET FI FR GB GH GR HK HR HU ID IE IL IN IR IS IT JO JP KE KR LT LV MA MX MY NG NL NO NZ PE PH PK PL PT RO RS RU SA SE SG SI SK SN TH TN TR TW TZ UA UG US VN YE ZA'/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Sports' label='Sports' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:assignable/>
    <yt:browsable regions='AE AR AU BD BE BG BR CA CL CO CZ DE DK DZ EE EG ES ET FI FR GB GH GR HK HR HU ID IE IL IN IR IS IT JO JP KE KR LT LV MA MX MY NG NL NO NZ PE PH PK PL PT RO RS RU SA SE SG SI SK SN TH TN TR TW TZ UA UG US VN YE ZA'/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Shortmov' label='Short Movies' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Travel' label='Travel &amp; Events' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:assignable/>
    <yt:browsable regions='AE AR AU BD BE BG BR CA CL CO CZ DE DK DZ EE EG ES ET FI FR GB GH GR HK HR HU ID IE IL IN IR IS IT JO JP KE KR LT LV MA MX MY NG NL NO NZ PE PH PK PL PT RO RS RU SA SE SG SI SK SN TH TN TR TW TZ UA UG US VN YE ZA'/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Games' label='Gaming' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:assignable/>
    <yt:browsable regions='AE AR AU BD BE BG BR CA CL CO CZ DE DK DZ EE EG ES ET FI FR GB GH GR HK HR HU ID IE IL IN IR IS IT JO JP KE KR LT LV MA MX MY NG NL NO NZ PE PH PK PL PT RO RS RU SA SE SG SI SK SN TH TN TR TW TZ UA UG US VN YE ZA'/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Videoblog' label='Videoblogging' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='People' label='People &amp; Blogs' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:assignable/>
    <yt:browsable regions='AE AR AU BD BE BG BR CA CL CO CZ DE DK DZ EE EG ES ET FI FR GB GH GR HK HR HU ID IE IL IN IR IS IT JO JP KE KR LT LV MA MX MY NG NL NO NZ PE PH PK PL PT RO RS RU SA SE SG SI SK SN TH TN TR TW TZ UA UG US VN YE ZA'/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Comedy' label='Comedy' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:assignable/>
    <yt:browsable regions='AE AR AU BD BE BG BR CA CL CO CZ DE DK DZ EE EG ES ET FI FR GB GH GR HK HR HU ID IE IL IN IR IS IT JO JP KE KR LT LV MA MX MY NG NL NO NZ PE PH PK PL PT RO RS RU SA SE SG SI SK SN TH TN TR TW TZ UA UG US VN YE ZA'/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Entertainment' label='Entertainment' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:assignable/>
    <yt:browsable regions='AE AR AU BD BE BG BR CA CL CO CZ DE DK DZ EE EG ES ET FI FR GB GH GR HK HR HU ID IE IL IN IR IS IT JO JP KE KR LT LV MA MX MY NG NL NO NZ PE PH PK PL PT RO RS RU SA SE SG SI SK SN TH TN TR TW TZ UA UG US VN YE ZA'/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='News' label='News &amp; Politics' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:assignable/>
    <yt:browsable regions='AE AR AU BD BE BG BR CA CL CO CZ DE DK DZ EE EG ES ET FI FR GB GH GR HK HR HU ID IE IL IN IR IS IT JO JP KE KR LT LV MA MX MY NG NL NO NZ PE PH PK PL PT RO RS RU SA SE SG SI SK SN TH TN TR TW TZ UA UG US VN YE ZA'/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Howto' label='Howto &amp; Style' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:assignable/>
    <yt:browsable regions='AE AR AU BD BE BG BR CA CL CO CZ DE DK DZ EE EG ES ET FI FR GB GH GR HK HR HU ID IE IL IN IR IS IT JO JP KE KR LT LV MA MX MY NG NL NO NZ PE PH PK PL PT RO RS RU SA SE SG SI SK SN TH TN TR TW TZ UA UG US VN YE ZA'/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Education' label='Education' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:assignable/>
    <yt:browsable regions='AE AR AU BD BE BG BR CA CL CO CZ DE DK DZ EE EG ES ET FI FR GB GH GR HK HR HU ID IE IL IN IR IS IT JO JP KE KR LT LV MA MX MY NG NL NO NZ PE PH PK PL PT RO RS RU SA SE SG SI SK SN TH TN TR TW TZ UA UG US VN YE ZA'/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Tech' label='Science &amp; Technology' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:assignable/>
    <yt:browsable regions='AE AR AU BD BE BG BR CA CL CO CZ DE DK DZ EE EG ES ET FI FR GB GH GR HK HR HU ID IE IL IN IR IS IT JO JP KE KR LT LV MA MX MY NG NL NO NZ PE PH PK PL PT RO RS RU SA SE SG SI SK SN TH TN TR TW TZ UA UG US VN YE ZA'/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Nonprofit' label='Nonprofits &amp; Activism' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:assignable/>
    <yt:browsable regions='US'/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Movies' label='Movies' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Movies_anime_animation' label='Anime/Animation' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Movies_action_adventure' label='Action/Adventure' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Movies_classics' label='Classics' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Movies_comedy' label='Comedy' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Movies_documentary' label='Documentary' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Movies_drama' label='Drama' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Movies_family' label='Family' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Movies_foreign' label='Foreign' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Movies_horror' label='Horror' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Movies_sci_fi_fantasy' label='Sci-Fi/Fantasy' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Movies_thriller' label='Thriller' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Movies_shorts' label='Shorts' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Shows' label='Shows' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
  <atom:category term='Trailers' label='Trailers' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <yt:deprecated/>
  </atom:category>
</app:categories>
```